# PHP How to read entire TXT file

Tags: php, html

Good Day All
I have a .php file which I want to edit via fopen() and file_get_content() functions. However, my file contains some php codes as well and I managed to get the content out of my file but without the php part. Also, I have tried the eval() (I know it's not suggested!) function with same results. I was wondering if there could be a way to get whatever is inside that file regardless wether it's text or codes.
Thanks

Here is the code I used:

```
public function editwarning()
    {
        $filename = "http://www.parkho.ir/admin/templates/pm/email_warning.php";
        $content = file_get_contents($filename);
        echo $content;

    }
```

Comment: provide code you have tried....

Comment: I edited my question with the code I used.

Comment: Try `echo htmlspecialchars($content);`

Comment: Make sure you have enabled `allow_url_fopen` on your server may be in `php.ini`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1) pass the file PATH to the `$filename` var:

```
$filename = "/var/www/app/email_warning.php"; // <--- replace /var/www/app for your path
```

2) Or You need to use `htmlentities()`:

```
<?php
$content = htmlentities(file_get_contents($filename));
echo $data;
```